# Given an input, print all exponents where the base and power sum to the input

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic

So this is my first challenge on this site.

The challenge is to take in an input integer \$n\$, which will be positive, and print, in ascending order (\$1\$ to \$n\$, **including n**), the output of \$i^{(n-i)}\$ (where \$i\$ is the current integer).

## Example

Given the input 5, the program will print:

```
1  
8  
9  
4  
1
```

\$1^4\$ is 1 and \$1+4=5\$
\$2^3\$ is 8 and \$2+3=5\$
\$3^2\$ is 9 and \$3+2=5\$
\$4^1\$ is 4 and \$4+1=5\$
\$5^0\$ is 1 and \$5+0=5\$

## Input and Output

Input will be in the form of a positive integer.
Output will be a list of numbers, delimited by either commas or new lines.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.

Comment: the comma/newline detail should be omitted, it is normal practice around here to let output of lists be in any convenient format, including as a list/array object being returned by a function

Comment: Is the input always greater than 0 or do we have to deal with 0 and negatives?

Comment: Inputs will always be positive

Comment: Two equally short answers doesn't matter. If you feel like accepting an answer, choose the earliest posted one. *However* I **strongly** recommend waiting at least a few days, and would suggest never accepting an answer (to encourage more submissions).

Comment: Are we allowed to start with 0^n or must we start at 1?

Comment: Shouldn't the title be "Given an **integer**, print all the **powers obtained with a base and an exponent that** sum to the input"?

Comment: is a trailing comma at the end of the output allowed?

Comment: You can have a trailing comma, since it doesn't interfere with the primary objective

Comment: @NicolaSap Should probably also be a **positive integer**.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>8</s> 5 bytes

```apl
⍳*⊢-⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/@v8ahvql/wo941mnogZrCrXqizr4t6Un6FQn6egm6abX6e@qOuxal5iUk5qcGOPiFADlCdc6R6cWJOibomF5Dj6f@obYLB/0c9ex91zHjUu1nrUe8KQ20g438aUOJRbx9ETVfzofXGj9omgqwJcgaSIR6ewf8f9a5KOwRRbmgAAA)

Anonymous prefix tacit function. TIO tests for the range [1..10].

Thanks @lirtosiast for 3 bytes.

#### How:

```apl
⍳*⊢-⍳ ⍝ Tacit function
    ⍳ ⍝ Range. ⍳n generates the vector [1..n].
  ⊢- ⍝ Subtracted from the argument. The vector is now [n-1,n-2,...,0]
⍳*    ⍝ Exponentiate using the range [1..n] as base. The result is the vector
      ⍝ [1^(n-1), 2^(n-2), 3^(n-3),...]
```

Comment: `⍳*⊢-⍳` is 5 bytes, using `⎕IO←1`.

Comment: @lirtosiast took me a while to figure out why does that work, but I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 19 bytes

```perl6
{^$_+1 Z**[R,] ^$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzpOJV7bUCFKSys6SCdWAcir/Z@WX6RgqmOpY2isUM3FWZxYqaCnlsZV@x8A)

Anonymous code block that takes a number and returns a list. Zip exponents the range `1 to input` and the range `input-1 to 0`

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 23 bytes

```
f i=[x^(i-x)|x<-[1..i]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00h0za6Ik4jU7dCs6bCRjfaUE8vMzb2f25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQpqC6X8A)

Alternative version, also 23 bytes:

```
f i=(^)<*>(i-)<$>[1..i]
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Aheui (esotope)](https://github.com/aheui/pyaheui), <s>193</s> 164 bytes (56 chars)

```
방빠싹받분샥퍼붇바파쟈뿌차샦히망맣여
타빠바푸투반또분뽀뿌서썪삯타삯받반타
석차샦져쌲볼어타토싻삭빠쏛ㅇ또섞썪뻐
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7BCoJAFEX3/k8f1CKoD2gvOqXQSAZRgmlClBVGQ4UoGn1My/vmG6Y3tHlcePcc7nA8mk6MgbqgLWjRQqWoBflHHfWoA6i1lpL2IT6S1Jn8k85DlBnKA20rR/suY7a0anRYQSVIYubxdi0gdhRdybtzja9Vq4SzQyL7y6hoSD7w7Gnz4oee84SOvJvdsky/s4B1JHK2oIuNGfwA)

[Try it on AVIS](https://aheui.github.io/avis/)(**Korean**); just copy and paste code above, press start button, input a number, see how it moves. To see output, press the **>_** icon on left side.

---

It's not golfed much, but I give it a shot.

Comment: Is it possible to chose a character set, so that each character is stored in 2 bytes?

Comment: @tsh According to [Aheui specification](http://aheui.github.io/specification.en), an Aheui code consists of only UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 5):

## Japt, 5 bytes

```
õ_p´U
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=9V9wtFU=&input=OA==)

```
õ         :Range [1,input]
 _        :Map
  p       :  Raise to the power of
   ´U     :  Input decremented
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
_m^-Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pz43Tjfw/39TAA)

Optimally encoded this would be 4.106 bytes.

```
_                reverse of the following list:
 m               map the following lambda d:
  ^                (N-d)**d
   -Qd             
      d
       Q         over [0,...,N-1]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 10 bytes

```
(>:^|.)@i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8F/DziquRk/TIVPvvyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRdXanJGvkKagimMYQJjGBr8BwA)

### If we really need to separate the numbers by a newline:

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 13 bytes

```
,.@(>:^|.)@i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8F9Hz0HDziquRk/TIVPvvyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRdXanJGvkKagimEoa6rq6sOEzPBImZo8B8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
R*ḶU$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9I6@GObaEq////NwUA)

```
R                [1,...,n]
 *               to the power of
  ḶU$            [0,...,n-1] reversed
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 18 bytes

```matlab
@(n)(t=1:n).^(n-t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNPU6PE1tAqT1MvTiNPt0Tzf5ptYl4xV5qGqeZ/AA)

Thanks [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo), using internal variable saves 3 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 32 bytes

```php
while($argn)echo++$i**--$argn,_;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0c987739bbeb6317fc43a8a63bcbabdf4ce0f4e8).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
*ạ¥€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/r4a6Fh5Y@alrz//9/UwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```javascript
n=>(g=i=>--n?++i**n+[,g(i)]:1)``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k4j3TbT1k5XN89eWztTSytPO1onXSNTM9bKUDMh4b91cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoappuZ/AA)

-3 bytes with credits to @Shaggy, and -1 byte by @l4m2!

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 36 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,i=1)=>n--?[i++**n,...f(n,i)]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjTyfT1lDT1i5PV9c@OlNbW0srT0dPTy8NJKEZaxUd@986OT@vOD8nVS8nP10jTcNUU/M/AA)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 37 bytes

```javascript
n=>[...Array(n)].map(x=>++i**--n,i=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5aT0/PsagosVIjTzNWLzexQKPC1k5bO1NLS1c3TyfT1kDzv3Vyfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqmm5n8A)

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQ62wugz76KWZXmZiKITMyur69d/nP9/CU@7XazjgSD2UHmQs7a/UgKsYoySSUoeC2oMjYQ9Peapxry5BgRRw/)

Comment: [32](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k4j3TbT1k5XN89eWztTSytPO1onXSNTM9bKUDMh4b91cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoappuZ/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>24</s> <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
(x=Range@#)^(#-x)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7872Zl@1@jwjYoMS891UFZM05DWbdCU@1/QFFmXkm0W7RpbOx/AA)

-4 thanks @lirtosiast.

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 6 bytes

```
rx\╒m#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7@oIubR1Em5yv//m3JZchkaAwA)

Comment: I have implemented reverse subtraction, multiplication and division, but it looks like a reverse power operator could come in handy?

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 40 bytes

```python
lambda n:[i**(n-i)for i in range(1,n+1)]   #Outputs a list
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjpTS0sjTzdTMy2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw1AnT9tQM/Z/QVFmXolCmoapJheMaYJgGiIxDTT/AwA)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```python
n,i=input(),0
exec"print(n-i)**i;i+=1;"*n   #Prints in reversed order
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P08n0zYzr6C0RENTx4ArtSI1WamgKDOvRCNPN1NTSyvTOlPb1tBaSSvv/39TAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 27 bytes

```ruby
->n{(1..n).map{|r|r**n-=1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNQTy9PUy83saC6pqimSEsrT9fWsLb2f4FCWrRpLBeIMjSM/Q8A)

Answer (score 2):

### QBasic, <s>35</s>33 bytes

Thank you @Neil for 2 bytes!

```
INPUT a
FOR b=1TO a
?b^(a-b)
NEXT
```

Slightly expanded version on [REPL.IT](https://repl.it/@pimsteenbergh/MasculineDarksalmonApplicationpackage) because the interpreter in't entirely up-to-spec.

**Output**

```
QBasic (qb.js)
Copyright (c) 2010 Steve Hanov
   
   5
1
8
9
4
1
```

Comment: Save 2 bytes by outputting the list in the correct order! (`b^(a-b)` for `b=1..a`)

Comment: @Neil Thanks, I've worked it in!

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 35 bytes

```
.+
*
_
$$.($.'*$($.>`$*)_¶
%~`^
.+¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS4srnktFRU9DRU9dSwVI2iWoaGnGH9rGpVqXEMelp31o2///pgA) Explanation:

```
.+
*
```

Convert the input to unary.

```
_
```

Match each position. This then sets several replacement variables. `` $` `` becomes the left of the match; `` $>` `` modifies this to be the left and match; `` $.>` `` modifies this to take the length, i.e. the current index. `$'` meanwhile is the right of the match, so `$.'` is the length i.e. the current exponent.

```
$$.($.'*$($.>`$*)_¶
```

Create a string `$.(` plus `$.'` repetitions of `` $.>`* `` plus `_`. For an example, for an index of 2 in an original input of 5, `$.'` is 3 and `` $.>` `` is 2 so the resulting string is `$.(2*2*2*_`. This conveniently is a Retina replacement expression that caluclates 2³. Each string is output on its own line.

```
%~`^
.+¶
```

For each line generated by the previous stage, prefix a line `.+` to it, turning it into a replacement stage, and evaluate that stage, thereby calculating the expression.

Answer (score 2):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 42 bytes

```fs
let f x=Seq.map(fun y->pown y (x-y))[1..x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/Pye1RCFNocI2OLVQLzexQCOtNE@hUteuIL8cSCtoVOhWampGG@rpVcT@LyjKzCtJy1NQUnVUUtAAaSjJ98ksLtFIUzDV1PwPAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 59 Bytes

```
for(int i=1;a+1>i;i++)System.out.println(Math.pow(i,a-i));
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. It looks like this requires "input" be assigned to the predefined variable `a`, which we don't allow.

Comment: Hello, here's a fix for you: `n->{for(int i=0;i++<n;)System.out.println(Math.pow(i,n-i));}` [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##bU7BTsMwDL33K6xJkxK6RuNKVi6cdthpR8QhpO1waZ0ocTahqd9ewlRAQhysZ7/3/OzenE3VN@8zjt4Fhj7PKjEOqktkGR2pO1349DqgBTuYGOFgkOBaACxsZMMZzg4bGLMmjhyQTs8vYMIpypsVYE/85CimsQ3QQT1T9XjtXBBIDFhvNZbljrQ8fkRuR@USK59TeCBxMPymvLsI3FCFUupp1rfIn3Wo4V5n2GXc5qYsv68C/A3sxGrdPKxptQGUejF1yljbeha/1D@PLNpUfNU0fwI) (code and test cases in the link)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 46 bytes

```cs
x=>new int[x].Select((_,i)=>Math.Pow(i+1,--x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxCsIwEADQvV9xdEowCTg4tc2moCgIHRxEpMarHtQLpAnN38dOb3lu1m6mckjsWuKo4Ljn9MMwvCZs3z6tWAsjdFByZxkXWNc9P0yPE7ooxFOR7OxliF9z9YugzVZpnaUsTVXdAkU8E6PoYyD@mJMnFjXUCkaxk1I25Q8)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
:Gy-^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38q9Ujfu/39TAA)

#### Explanation

Consider input `5` as an example.

```
:     % Implicit input. Range
      % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5]
G     % Push input again
      % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5], 5
y     % Duplicate from below
      % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5], 5, [1 2 3 4 5]
-     % Subtract, element-wise
      % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5], [4 3 2 1 0]
^     % Power, element-wise. Implicit display
      % STACK: [1 8 9 4 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 37 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$n=[i^(n-i)\\i<-[1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r4xLJc82OjNOI083UzMmJtNGN9pQTy8vNvZ/cEkiUJGtgoqC6f9/yWk5ienF/3U9ff67VOYl5mYmFwMA)

Defines `$ :: Int -> [Int]` taking an integer and returning the list of results.

```
$ n                // function $ of n
 = [i ^ (n-i)      // i to the power of n minus i
    \\ i <- [1..n] // for each i in 1 to n
   ]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 34 bytes

```r
x=1:scan();cat(x^rev(x-1),sep=',')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8LW0Ko4OTFPQ9M6ObFEoyKuKLVMo0LXUFOnOLXAVl1HXfO/6X8A)

Comment: Is the default "sep" not a space? Would that not work?

Comment: @stuartstevenson "Output will be a list of numbers, delimited by either commas or new lines."

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <strike>43</strike> 41 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to *@Shaggy*

```lua
s=io.read()for i=1,s do print(i^(s-i))end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/2DYzX68oNTFFQzMtv0gh09ZQp1jbQCElX6GgKDOvRCMzTqNYN1NTMzUv5f9/UwA)

Comment: I don't think you need the `+0`; seems to work without it.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LD<Rm
```

Port of [*@lirtosiast*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176669/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx8UmKPf/f1MA)

**Explanation:**

```python
L      # List in the range [1, (implicit) input integer]
       #  i.e. 5 → [1,2,3,4,5]
 D<    # Duplicate this list, and subtract 1 to make the range [0, input)
       #  i.e. [1,2,3,4,5] → [0,1,2,3,4]
   R   # Reverse it to make the range (input, 0]
       #  i.e. [0,1,2,3,4] → [4,3,2,1,0]
    m  # Take the power of the numbers in the lists (at the same indices)
       # (and output implicitly)
       #  i.e. [1,2,3,4,5] and [4,3,2,1,0] → [1,8,9,4,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, 22 bytes

```
n=scan();(1:n)^(n:1-1)
```

Fairly self-explanatory; note that the `:` operator is higher precendence than the `-` operator so that `n:1-1` is shorter than `(n-1):0`

If we are allowed to start at 0, then we can lose two bytes by using `(0:n)^(n:0)` avoiding the need for a -1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
Ｉ⮌ＥＮＸ⁻θιι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEIyi1LLWoOFXDN7FAwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NHISC/HMjwzcwrLdYo1FHI1ARhELD@/9/0v25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   Ｎ        Input as a number
  Ｅ         Map over implicit range
       ι    Current value
     ⁻      Subtracted from
      θ     First input
    Ｘ       Raised to power
        ι   Current value
 ⮌          Reverse list
Ｉ           Cast to string
             Implicitly print on separate lines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 55 bytes

```cs
v=>Enumerable.Range(0,v--).Select(i=>Math.Pow(i+1,v--))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpds45lXYmyko@Dpmleam1qUmJSTauOSXwqk7OwU0oAKFGwV/pfZ2iGk9YIS89JTNQx0ynR1NfWCU3NSk0s0Mm3tfBNLMvQC8ss1MrUNwXKa/625uMKLMktSfTLzUjUUgkuKMvPS9bzyM/M0FJR0QAhkgYaCqYImCFr/BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>80 bytes</s>, <s>71 bytes</s>, <s>63 bytes</s>, <s>59 bytes</s>, 56 bytes

```cpp
int n,c=1;cin>>n;for(;c<=n;++c){cout<<pow(c,n-c)<<endl;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcg5DsMgEADA3q9YKY3xUbhIBeYvm4XYSGZBHHJh5e0krtKNhmKc6UDe2sMxHdVYUC7kkix63f2PPJZddzU73oDR2xyRLORiZOe4gEfH/Q2cgHZMMAwvcbV7eKJ1keRYa5bvkHpJamU5jiQuCrUoFcPZ08QzCaUsm0N@WrKlJoblx2f7Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 21 bytes

```perl
say++$\**--$_ while$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJbWyVGS0tXVyVeoTwjMydVJf7/f9N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/uvmAQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 22 bytes

```
n->[i^(n-i)|i<-[1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7P0/XLjozTiNPN1OzJtNGN9pQTy8vNvZ/QVFmXolGmoappuZ/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 39 bytes

```powershell
param($n)1..$n|%{"1"+"*$_"*($n-$_)|iex}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVP01BPTyWvRrVayVBJW0lLJV5JCyiqqxKvWZOZWlH7//9/UwA)

Because exponents are expensive in Powershell, this works by using invoke-expression to parse and calculate the string "1*n*n...*n" Works because the first and last entry are always 1.

Comment: Nice. The length of `param($n)1..$n|%{[Math]::Pow($_,$n-$_)}` is 39 bytes too :)

Comment: @mazzy I actually did check that after posting this and chuckled at finding out.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gambit Scheme (gsi)](http://gambitscheme.org), 52 bytes

```scm
(lambda(x)(map(lambda(y)(expt y(-x y)))(iota x 1)))
```

For some reason this code does not appear to work on TIO. It works fine on my machine.

**Explanation:**

```scm
(lambda(x)(map(lambda(y)(expt y(- x y)))(iota x 1)))    Full program
(lambda(x)                                        )    Anonymous function with arg x
          (map(lambda(y)              )(iota x 1))     Map over the range 1 to input
                        (expt y                        Raises the mapped value to...
                               (- x y)                 The input value minus the mapped value (this powers the list by the reverse)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
RD$_*
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPVJEJTI0XyomZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD01JmZsYWdzPWU=)

##### Explanation

```python
RD$_*  # Implicit input
R      # Push [1..input]
 D     # Duplicate
  $_   # Subtract from input
    *  # Exponentiate
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (`-lm`), 52 bytes

```c
f(n,i){for(i=n;i--;printf("%.0f\n",pow(n-i,i)));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzBCsIwEETv/YqlIGxKIvXgKeiPqIewsHGh3ZRY6qH0143J7c28YchFolIY1YrZOWWUm3pxzi9ZdGXsT@eRn9rbJX1RndSZMf4oVcIcRLFByJEs0DtkGIYaNgN7ByCMzcAdRgOV1ySt2B6XV/3ojlKuP@IpxE9x0/wH)

Comment: Can't you just use %.f withouth the 0?
Also, in a trailing comma is allowed, youcan replace \n with ,

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 11 chars, 22 bytes

```
{⍪⍵*⌽⍵-1}∘⍳
```

test:

```
  f←{⍪⍵*⌽⍵-1}∘⍳
  f 5
1
8
9
4
1
```

Answer (score 0):

**SAS, 71 bytes**

```
data a;input n;o=cat(1);do x=1 to n-1;o=catx(',',(n-x)**x,o);end;cards;
```

Input goes after the `cards;` statement, separated by newlines, like so:

```
data a;input n;o=cat(1);do x=1 to n-1;o=catx(',',(n-x)**x,o);end;cards;
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Outputs a dataset containing the input `n`, and comma-separated output string `o` (and also helper variable `x`)

```
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+
| n  |                                            o                                             | x  |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+
¦ 1  ¦ 1                                                                                        ¦ 1  ¦
¦ 2  ¦ 1,1                                                                                      ¦ 2  ¦
¦ 3  ¦ 1,2,1                                                                                    ¦ 3  ¦
¦ 4  ¦ 1,4,3,1                                                                                  ¦ 4  ¦
¦ 5  ¦ 1,8,9,4,1                                                                                ¦ 5  ¦
¦ 6  ¦ 1,16,27,16,5,1                                                                           ¦ 6  ¦
¦ 7  ¦ 1,32,81,64,25,6,1                                                                        ¦ 7  ¦
¦ 8  ¦ 1,64,243,256,125,36,7,1                                                                  ¦ 8  ¦
¦ 9  ¦ 1,128,729,1024,625,216,49,8,1                                                            ¦ 9  ¦
¦ 10 ¦ 1,256,2187,4096,3125,1296,343,64,9,1                                                     ¦ 10 ¦
¦ 11 ¦ 1,512,6561,16384,15625,7776,2401,512,81,10,1                                             ¦ 11 ¦
¦ 12 ¦ 1,1024,19683,65536,78125,46656,16807,4096,729,100,11,1                                   ¦ 12 ¦
¦ 13 ¦ 1,2048,59049,262144,390625,279936,117649,32768,6561,1000,121,12,1                        ¦ 13 ¦
¦ 14 ¦ 1,4096,177147,1048576,1953125,1679616,823543,262144,59049,10000,1331,144,13,1            ¦ 14 ¦
¦ 15 ¦ 1,8192,531441,4194304,9765625,10077696,5764801,2097152,531441,100000,14641,1728,169,14,1 ¦ 15 ¦
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 47 bytes

```c
i;f(a){for(i=a;i;printf("%.f,",pow(i,a-i--)));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DckxCoAwDADAWV8hBSGBxs0p@JhQiARqW1RwEL9u9NZLlLKU1d1YQfDWuoMtwsZtt3IqhHHSGGKrF1gUMiJE5Mf/HDaxAnj3ncKM3D/@Js2yHk55@wA)

Prints in reverse order, delimited with commas.

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 20 bytes

```
$->n[map n'i->i^n-i]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?ip4lzc)